# does a blocked signal also a pending signal?

Tags: c, signals

we know that applications can explicitly block and unblock selected signals using the `sigprocmask` function, so let's say we have used this function to block `SIGINT`, so the kernel sets the corresponding bit in the blocked vector. If we run the program and press Ctrl + C to send `SIGINT`, since this signal is currently blocked, there is no action to the process( the process won't be terminated).

My question is, even though this signal is blocked, will kernel also sets the corresponding bit in the pending vector so that when we unblock this signal, `SIGINT` in the pending will be immediately receiving by the process? or the previous `SIGINT` doesn't count and you have to trigger a new `SIGINT`?

Comment: Yes, the signal will be considered 'pending' and will be delivered immediately upon unblock. (Not an answer only because i'm on a tablet and therefore it would be far too much work to look up the relevant bits of POSIX to back up this assertion.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how (or if) the behavior will vary from platform to platform, or library implementation to implementation, but:

> https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html
>
> A signal may be blocked, which means that it will not be delivered
> until it is later unblocked.  Between the time when it is generated
> and when it is delivered a signal is said to be pending.

So yes, to answer your question, the Ctl-C would be "pending", and should be delivered if you unblock SIGINT.

It's also worth considering [sigaction()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), which would allow your process to completely *ignore* the signal.

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking of another function but isn't `sigaction` deprecated in favor of `signal`?

Comment: @DanielWalker: If anything `signal` is deprecated in favor of `sigaction` -- that is the newer and more capable interface.  While `signal` is not actually deprecated, just old, you should not use it unless you need to deal with an ancient pre-POSIX unix system.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I had those backwards.