# Ucontext gets blocked signal after swapcontext

Tags: c, signals, ucontext

I am blocking a `SIGINT` in `ucontext` A, for example, say I hit `^C (SIGINT)` while it is running, nothing happens as expected.

In context B, there is a `SIGINT` handler.
When I `swapcontext(A, B)` then `ucontext` B immediately executes the signal handler. Even though context A is the one that received and blocked this signal.
Is there a way to ensure process B does not enter the signal handler right away?

Comment: Blocking a signal is not the same as discarding it.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63866300/does-a-blocked-signal-also-a-pending-signal

Answer (score 0):

While I did not figure this out, using a critical flag, instead of blocking the signal was what I used.

Comment: please add some example in your answer.